# Shell: Sub command list/display

Tags: shell

I have written a shell script, it takes many commands. On pressing TAB key shell should list the commands. How to make it?
Br,
Praveen P B

Comment: For Ex: I have written a shell script check.sh. I do process based on command I pass as a first argument. Now when I type ./check.sh and TAB key it should list supported command.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the shell you're targeting. For bash, you'll want to read the chapters on [programmable completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) in the Bash Reference Manual.

Basically, you write a script for it and have users source it somewhere (usually by placing it in `/etc/bash_completion.d/` or similar; examining existing scripts there is probably a good idea, too).